# Как в visual studio зайти в выбор элементов панели элементов?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как в visual studio зайти в выбор элементов панели элементов  как на скриншоте 1,когда я захожу вид,панель элементов у меня выходит окно которое на рисунке 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на панели элементов нажимаете правую кнопку мыши и дальше "Выберите элементы" (Changes Item)

Comment: можете оформить как ответ дам лучшего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На панели элементов нажимаете правую кнопку мыши и дальше "**Выберите элементы**" (Changes Item)